# Reading Different Elements from Modbus-TCP

Tags: c#, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm trying to figure out how to read different values from a modbus device (Powerscout 24) for different elements. There is a manual [here](http://www.dentinstruments.com/hs-fs/hub/472997/file-2376767200-pdf/Pdf_Files/PS24_Manual.pdf?t=1459525636701) which says

> ADDRESSING AN ELEMENT
>
> The PowerScout 24 has eight elements. Modbus and BACnet each use
>   different ways to designate an element on the PS24. In Modbus mode,
>   the decimal network switches set the base address for metering element
>   “A.” Metering elements “B” through “H” will always have a Modbus
>   address that is one higher than the element before. For example, if
>   the rotary address switches are set to 001 then metering element “A”
>   register values will be accessed at Modbus address 001, element “B”
>   registers will be accessed at Modbus address 002, element “C” at
>   address 003, and so on.

So from my understanding, if i wanted to read the value at register 4012 on Element A (or Slave 1) I would read the holding register at 4012.

If i wanted to read Element B, the register would be 4013? But how can this be, 4013 is used for a different value - Displacement PF System. (Check top of page 65)

I've tried using this library [EasyModbusTCP](http://easymodbustcp.net/category/codesamples)

```
ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("192.168.1.250", 502);    //Ip-Address and Port of Modbus-TCP-Server
modbusClient.Connect();                                                    
int[] readHoldingRegisters = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(4000,1);
//Read 10 Holding Registers from Server, starting with Address 1
```

I've tested this and it works in the sense that it can only read registers for element A (slave 1). I havent been able to figure out how to read registers for the other elements.

I checked the other part of the library (RTU - read from serial ports) and this defines a slave to read from, but I need to read the device over TCP not serial so I cant implement it this way.

Can anyone explain how I can read different elements via TCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to reading specific elements (Slaves). From the easy modbustcp you can change the UnitIdentifier of the modbus client.

```
modbusClient.UnitIdentifier = 3;
```

This will make any reads to the modbus client read from the 3rd element.